# insert into database error SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, connection

i have been on the busy with this script to save the data from this form

the connect.php sets up my connection to the database

(sorry for the dutch comments in between the code)

```
 <?php
 include('connect.php');
 //Gebruik de method ->exec(). Raadpleeg de reader hoe je deze method moet gebruiken. 

 $KijkerV =$_POST['KijkerV'];
 $KijkerT_V =$_POST['KijkerT_V']; 
 $KijkerA=$_POST['KijkerA'];
 $Email = $_POST['Email'];
  $ShowId = $_POST['ShowId'];

 try { 

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO tblkijker (Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, Email, ShowId) 
  VALUES (:Kijkerv, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :Email, :ShowId'; 

  //het statement wordt toegevoegd aan een pdo statement object 
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
  //koppelen van parameters in de query string met de te inserten waardes 
  $s->bindValue(':Kijkerv', $KijkerV, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $s->bindValue(':KijkerT_V', $KijkerT_V, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $s->bindValue(':KijkerA', $KijkerA, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $s->bindValue(':Email', $Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
  $s->bindValue(':ShowId', $ShowId, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  var_dump($KijkerV);
 var_dump($KijkerT_V);
 var_dump($KijkerA);
 var_dump($Email);
 var_dump($ShowId);
 var_dump($sql);
 var_dump($S);
  //Nu kan de query worden uitgevoerd 
  $s->execute(); 
  //id is een auto_increment veld is nu bepaald 
  $Stoelnummer = $pdo->lastInsertId(); 
  $output = "Uw kaarten zijn gereseveerd u heeftb stoelnummer: ".$Stoelnummer; 

 } 
 catch (PDOException $e) 
 { 
  $output = 'Fout bij inserten van een rij: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
 } 
?> 
<html> 
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
 <?php echo $output ?> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

the **error** that is making its appearance:
Fout bij inserten van een rij: (as set with the catch)

```
 error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Are parameters case-sensitive?  `:email` and `:Email` are different.

Comment: You forgot to close the sql statement as well `:ShowId'); `

Comment: You have 4 column names -> `(Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, Email)` but 5 parameters -> `(:KijkerV, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :email, :ShowId`. This is in addition to the 2 previous comments

Comment: i have fixed these all now. thanks alot.
new error i am afraid

Comment: You still have not closed your `VALUES` that @AbhikChakraborty provided -> `VALUES (:Kijkerv, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :Email, :ShowId` needs to be `VALUES (:Kijkerv, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :Email, :ShowId)` -> missing closing `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not close the parantheses.

This:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tblkijker (Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, Email, ShowId) 
VALUES (:Kijkerv, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :Email, :ShowId';
```

Should be

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tblijker (Kijkerv, KijkerT_V, KijkerA, Email, ShowId)
VALUES (:Kijkv, :KijkerT_V, :KijkerA, :Email, :ShowId)';
```

This should probably fix the error you're getting.